# What is the cause of imaginary dialogues in mind?

Tags: personal-practice, self, attachment

Most of the time, I have conversations in mind. Most of them, there is person , interviewing me. Other person: *"Why don't you like that ?"* Me: *"I don't like it because ..."*

This doesn't happen in real world because it is an egoish thing. What is the cause of this ?. Is this the pride ? How do I stop this without forcing it ? (I'm aware of these kind of thoughts and I turn the direction when I caught them.)

I am looking for an answer according to the Buddhism.

Comment: This phenomenon is sometimes also called an "inner dialogue" or "inner monologue".

Comment: @ChrisW, is it bad ?

Comment: @Dum Most/all of us have it. It's just the way our brain is wired. (Recently i have seen people claiming they have no inner dialogue, but i find that rare). As already pointed out, in meditation it's called vitakka and vicara, and is considered a healthy examination of our inner workings. Outside of meditation one can arguably call the inner monologue "vaci sankhara", which essentially is a result of our karma. Good or bad, it's just there, simply put.

Comment: @Erik but it is all about **me**. *"I am not like that. Because .......", "I don't recommend that ...."* Thanks :)

Comment: @Erik Am I lowering others ?

Comment: @Dum i'm not sure i understand your question, but i didn't see it that way. Also, i believe it's important that you try to find your own answers to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

It's about [the first Governor](http://accesstoinsight.eu/en/tipitaka/sut/an/an03/an03.040.than) arguing with the defilement or vici versa. Nothing wrong and very needed till the final abounding of even this relation. Just don't mix them, since the defilement are smart in tricking.

*[Note that this isn't given for stacks, exchange, trade or what ever keeps one bond in the wheel]*

Comment: You are always come up with best resources. Thank you very much :) It is very helpful.

Comment: [Mudita](http://forum.sangham.net/index.php?topic=326.msg13806#msg13806), the Buddha himself had this, what others call 'wired' all along his way, used and the Tipitaka is full of such dialogues. Sometimes with Devas and Gods as well and of course with Mara.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it is called Vitakka and Vicara.
Vitakka and Vicara stop at first Jhana.

Answer (score 1):

You have asked what is the 'cause' of vitakka and vicara (the inner dialog). The idea of 'cause' should be let go* and the idea of 'association' should be substituted.

Vitakka and vicara arise as a consequence of contact with named-forms + consciousness.

Things are all named-forms + consciousness. When attention is brought to a thing three things arise in association: the form of the thing and its identification (name) and awareness thereof.

A string of such perceptions of named-form + consciousness constitutes a thought. Thoughts arise to one; are not generated within.

Those thoughts become the subject of attention and consideration and inquiry and reasoning and analysis; that is vicara; 'pondering'.

The first (vitakka) should be observed as coming from without in order to evaluate it objectively and/or pass it along to vicara or let it go.

Vicara will stop when one has observed the external nature of vitakka and has let it go.

-----
Today the term 'cause' is used way too carelessly. Cause is a mystery. We cannot 'see' cause. What we can see is association. WHEN this arises, THAT arises; not WHEN this arises, this is the CAUSE.